# npm install will remove packages

Tags: angular, webpack, npm-install

My website is Angular 4 (created by [Microsoft ASP.NET Core JavaScript Services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices))

While publishing website,  it needs to run "npm install" to check modules, after "npm install" I found some packages is disappear. But I don't know why "npm install" will removes this packages. Please help, Thank you.

PS:
When I run npm install, it shows:

```
>npm install
- @types/jquery@3.2.12 node_modules\@types\jquery
- @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.1 node_modules\@agm\core
- @types/bootbox@4.4.34 node_modules\@types\bootbox
- bootbox@4.4.0 node_modules\bootbox
- ng2-file-upload@1.2.1 node_modules\ng2-file-upload
```

And my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Angular4Web",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/bootbox": "4.4.34",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootbox": "^4.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "webpack": "https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/-/webpack-2.5.1.tgz"
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of npm do you use? Do you have npm-shrinkwrap.json or package-lock.json in your project root folder?

Comment: npm version is 4.1.2. I have npm-shrinkwrap.json in project .

Comment: By any chance have you checked your node_modules folder to see if the packages are indeed missing

Comment: What packages are removing by npm? They are listed in package.json?

Comment: bootbox & ng2-file-upload are removed, I do check node_modules folder and can't find this two module folders.

Comment: I check it again, five modules are all removed.

Comment: I upgrade npm  to the latest version and resolve this issue.